# Case insensitive search using a method in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a method called `get_obj_or_none` which returns an object or none.

```
def get_obj_or_none(model, **kwargs):
    try:
        return model.objects.get(**kwargs)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I'm getting the song name of a `Song` object in the variable `song_name`

I'm adding new objects as follows

```
if not get_obj_or_none(Song, name=song_name, artist=dj):
    s = Song(name=song_name, artist=dj, release_date=song['releaseDate'])
    s.save()
```

How can I do a case insensitive search in the `get_obj_or_none` method without adding a lower case `song_name` to the object's song name?

Comment: This is related to Django right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a case [insesitive match](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) by

`get_obj_or_none(Song, name__iexact=song_name, artist=dj)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass `name__iexact` instead of `name`.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-iexact)